# Java Null pointer exception on Webdriver wait statement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I get a null pointer error on WebDriver Wait statement using TestNG. I use a BaseClass my `@test` class.

This was working fine till last week but now is throwing a null pointer exception. If I remove the Wait statement, the script runs fine. Please advice. Below is the line

```
new WebDriverWait(BaseClass2.driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(getObject("NewButton"))));
```

Comment: How do you set value for `BaseClass2.driver`?

Comment: Code snippet is not enough to understand the error. Paste more of your code. At what line of code are you getting the error. Add more details to your question.